# Evaluating $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{h=K}^{\infty}he^{\frac{-(h-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dh$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, expected-value

Is there an analytical way to evaluate the above? (Basically evaluating the expectation of a normally distributed random variable over a specific range of values).

I've tried the following substitution, which hasn't really simplified the problem much:

$$y=\frac{-(h-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \leftrightarrow \sqrt{-2\sigma^2y} +\mu = h $$

$$\frac{dy}{dh}=\frac{\mu-h}{\sigma^2} \leftrightarrow dh=\frac{dy\sigma^2}{\mu-h}=\frac{dy\sigma^2}{-\sqrt{-2\sigma^2y}}$$

So:

$$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{h=K}^{\infty}he^{\frac{-(h-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dh=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{y=\frac{-(K-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}^{\infty}(\sqrt{-2\sigma^2y} +\mu)\frac{\sigma^2e^{y}}{-\sqrt{-2\sigma^2y}}dy=\\=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{y=\frac{-(K-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}^{\infty}-\sigma^2e^y-\frac{\mu\sigma^2e^y}{\sqrt{-2\sigma^2y}}dy$$

**To be clear, $K$, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are constants.**

Answer (score 1):

In general you can integrate this type of function. Integrate $e^{-x^2}$ is much more difficult. However you can use that

$$
\frac{d}{dx} e^{-x^2} = -2xe^{-x^2}
$$

Your given function looks basically like $xe^{-x^2}$ so given above antiderivative and using substitution, the integral should be much easier to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int h\,e^{\frac{-(h-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dh$$
Let
$$\frac{(h-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}=t^2\implies h=\mu +\sqrt{2} \sigma  t\implies dh=\sqrt{2} \sigma \,d t$$
$$I=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\Bigg[\mu\int e^{-t^2}\,dt+\sqrt{2} \sigma\int t \,e^{-t^2} \,dt \Bigg]$$ Thid first one is trivial and the secon even more if you write
$$\int t \,e^{-t^2} \,dt=\frac 12 \int  \,e^{-t^2} \,d(t^2)$$